# Finding corruption in a linked list

Tags: c++, c

I had an interview today for a developer position and was asked an interesting techincal question that i did not know the answer to. I will ask it here to see if anyone can provide me with a solution for my curiosity. It is a multi-part question:

1) You are given a singly linked list with 100 elements (integer and a pointer to next node), find a way to detect if there is a break or corruption halfway through the linked list? You may do anything with the linked list. Note that you must do this in the list as it is iterating and this is verification before you realise that the list has any issues with it.

Assuming that the break in the linked list is at the 50th element, the integer or even the pointer to the next node (51st element) may be pointing to a garbage value which is not necessarily an invalid address.

2) Note that if there is a corruption in the linked list, how would you minimize data loss?

Comment: "which is not necessarily an invalid address"  Barring C#'s unsafe keyword or some native interop (P/Invoke, JNI), how would you have a pointer to an invalid address in C# or Java?

Comment: You will first have to define "corrupt".

Comment: Is it really correct to tag this with C# and Java? They have no pointers (unless writing unsafe C# code) and a reference can't point to an invalid address. The question makes more sense in C or C++.

Comment: Is there any constraints on the integral value stored in the linked list?

Comment: "how would you minimize data loss?" - by writing code that works and has been tested....

Comment: Too few programming languages in the tag list. I vote for adding brainf*ck and malbolge as well

Comment: @zerkms I raise with Whitespace

Comment: Part 1 is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079099/corrupt-pointer-in-a-linked-list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test for a "corrupted" integer, you would need to know what the range of valid values is. Otherwise, there is no way to determine that the value in any given (signed) integer is invalid. So, assuming you have a validity test for the int, you would always check that value before iterating to the next element.

Testing for a corrupted pointer is trickier - for a start, what you need to do is check the value of the pointer to the next element before you attempt to de-reference it, and ensure it is a valid heap address. That will avoid a segmentation fault. The next thing is to validate that what the pointer points at is in fact a valid linked list node element - that's a bit trickier? Perhaps de-reference the pointer into a list element class/struct, and test the validity of the int and "next" pointer, if they are also good, then can be pretty sure the previous node was good also.

On 2), having discovered a corrupted node, [if the next pointer is corrupted] what you should do is set the "next pointer" of the previous node to 'NULL' immediately, marking it as the end of the list, and log your error etc etc.  if the corruption was just to the integer value, but not to the "next" element pointer, then you should remove that element from the list and link the previous and following nodes together instead - as no need to throw the rest of the list away in that case!

Comment: how could you check the whether the address is a valid heap address.

Comment: @peter, you could install a segfault handler and simply attempt to read from the pointer. If you don't get a segfault then it at least points somewhere you can read.

Comment: It's also important to test for the "corruption" case where the list contains a loop.  If you absolutely know the size (100) it's trivial, but my guess is removing that limit was going to be a follow-on question.  In-place loop detection is also not too difficult if you know the trick.

Comment: how do you know that the allocations are in the heap?

Answer (score 2):

If you at design time know that corruption may become a critical issue, you could add a "magic value" as a field into the node data structure which allows you to identify whether some data is likely to be a node or not. Or even to run through memory searching for nodes.

Or double some link information, i.e. store the address of the node after the next node in each node, such that you can recover if one link is broken.

The only problem I see is that you have to avoid segmentation faults.

Comment: "you have to avoid segmentation faults" - you always have to, not only in this particular case :-)

Comment: Yeah, but avoiding segmentation faults is more difficult if you cannot rely on the validity of your pointers.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part - Overload the new operator. When ever a new node is allocated allocate some additional space before and after the node and put some known values there. In traversal each node can be checked if it is in between the known values.

Answer (score 2):

If you can do anything to the linked list, what you can do is to calculate the checksum of each element and store it on the element itself.  This way you will be able to detect corruption even if it's a single bit error on the element.

To minimize data loss perhaps you can consider having storing the nextPtr in the previous element, that way if your current element is corrupted, you can always find the location of the next element from the previous.

Comment: The issue wit all this sort of answers is that you try to go back in either time or scope or both and construct the list or limit its contents as to ease the detection. There are all valid answers to subsets of the question but neither has anything to do with the problem as it is given.

Comment: That's true.  You can only do these before the list was built.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy question, and there are several possible answers.  Each trades off robustness with efficiency.  Since increased robustness is a prerequisite of the question being asked, there are solutions available which sacrifice both time (list traversal speed, as well as speed of insertion and speed of deletion of nodes) or alternately space (extra info stored with each node).  Now the problem has been stated that this is a fixed list of length 100, in which case the data structure of a linked list is most inappropriate.  Why not make the puzzle a little more challenging and say that the size of the list is not known a priori?

Answer (score -3):

Since the number of elements (100) is known, 100th node must contain a null pointer. If it does, the list with some good probability is valid (this cannot be guaranteed, if, for example, 99th node is corrupt and points to some memory location with all zeros). Otherwise, there is some problem (this can be returned as a fact).

**upd**: Also, it could be possible to, an every step, look at some structures `delete` would use if given the pointer, but since using `delete` itself is not safe in any sense, this is going to be implementation-specific.

Comment: That is wrong in so many levels. How about a corrupt node in the middle? You just "surf" around the memory like there's no tomorrow, when really it's all garbage, and only by luck you might stay in memory you are allowed to access, only to gamble that after 100 iterations you will have the value `0` as pointer. This fails thoroughly.

Comment: Incorrect solution, how can the list be traversed till the end if there are incorrect pointers in middle ?

Comment: @Yorye Nathan well, the moment you LEAVE the memory you are allowed to access you just catch the exception and say "the problem is BEFORE". Perfectly fine. The same if you discover null pointer before 100th element.

Comment: @DhruvPathak and what do you otherwise do if you encounter some pointer pointing to within the heap (this can be checked) other than looking at the other side? You are already "given a list". Not "allowed to construct one" as by Superman's answer.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev What if node #99 is corrupt, and by chance doesn't lead to non-accessible memory? And what if node #1 is corrupt? Pointing at itself, again, by chance? You are not guaranteed that it will ever change, and you are then stuck in an infinite loop. These cases are long shots, but they should be considered. The solution you provided is simply not safe at all. More over than that, you will have no way at all, knowing, or even estimating, where the corruption has begun.

Comment: @Yorye Nathan Finite loop, strictly speaking. You only havigate 100 nodes. I'll fix the answer to reflect it does not detect absence of the problem, sadly, only presence of it, with some good probability of success.