# How to resolve the corrupted pointer in the linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

If i found that a pointer(link) field in the linked list is corrupted, how i can resolve this problem?

I was asked this question in interview. I said no, its not possible to resolve it. Interviewer told its possible. Any ways are there?

Comment: How did you find out? *if* you find out, you would have a better logic than your programs's logic, and when you'd have a better logic, why not use it in the first place. (This is Godel's conjunction in disguise)

Comment: Indeed how did you find out? In the general case it is impossible...

Comment: please refer the answer for how to find out the corrupted pointer in the below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079099/corrupt-pointer-in-a-linked-list

Comment: @thrustmaster: I have been upvoting the answers which is logically correct for all the answers posted for my question..

Comment: Unsolicited general interview-related advice... Don't make unwarranted assumptions leading to unsatisfactory answers like you've given. Ask for details (singly-linked, doubly-linked, how we know it's corrupted, what resolve means, if memory at arbitrary addresses can be read without causing a crash, etc etc). If they give you no details, consider different cases of what would be if this and that was such and such, describe these cases and what can be possibly done in them.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that it's a doubly linked list:

If it's the "next" pointer that got corrupted, one can begin at the tail and using the "previous" pointer, traverse the list towards the head while maintaining a reference to the last element that was traversed. When you find the element that has the bad pointer, you simply need to make that element's "next" pointer point to the last element that was traversed.

If a "previous" link is corrupted in a doubly linked list, the process can be reversed - begin at the head, traverse until the bad "previous" pointer is found and fix it using the reference to the last element that was traversed.

Answer (score 0):

In developing my embedded job/s, I use forward-linked queues a lot.  I keep a count as well as the head pointer.  The queues have a check() method that runs round [count] links and calls the critical error handler if the resulting pointer is not the same as the head.  It's not foolproof, but it works sufficiently well to catch double-pushes and other such common queue errors.

NOTE: In multithreaded apps, the queue must be locked up to check it safely.

Answer (score 0):

In a doubly circular linked list, we can resolve the corrupted pointer, if any one of the pointer(previous or next pointer) is corrupted.

If next pointer is not proper, we can traverse the list reversely and then we can correct it, Or else if previous pointer is not proper, we can traverse the list forwardly to correct it.

Now we have to think how to identify a corrupted link(pointer) in a list. We use to  allocate dynamic memory(`malloc` or `calloc`) for each nodes separately. If we call `malloc` or `calloc` frequently for small small memory may affects to performance of the system. Rather than this we can allocate a big junk of heap memory at initial stage and then we can implement our own memory allocation function for each node creation. And also use this only for list node creation to identify corrupted links of the list.

This increases the performance of the system and also it will help to indentify whether the link of a node is corrupted or not, by checking the limits of the initial memory allocated for the list.

Once we get a pointer to a node, we have to do the below checks first before accessing the data in that node.

```
check_limit(node);
check_limit(node->next);
check_limit(node->previous);
```

And also we can check whether the `node->previous` is equal to `current_node`.

After this also there may be possibility of `node->next` might be pointing to wrong address but inside the initial memory limit. In this case we can read `node->next->previous` (this will not leads to crash, even if `next` is pointing wrong address but inside the initial memory limit) and check whether it is equal to `node` or not.

And also unused intial memory space should be `NULL` setted always (using `memset`).

By these ways we can find out the 99% of the corrupted pointers in a list.

Comment: I fail to see the logic. if `(one->next == two && two->prev != one)`, how do you know if [a] you have to set `two->prev = one;` or [b] that one->next was wrong in the first place? There is no way to tell. (there are simpler cases like if `(two->prev == three && three->next == two)`, which would indicate that one->next was wrong in the first case)

Answer (score 0):

In doubly circular linked list if corrupt pointer points one of the node's memory location then find the loop first using traverse and mark method. This will give location of the node that has corrupt pointer then treverse in reverse order then find out a node which has prev node location as the first step resulted node. Assign corrupt node's pointer next this node. Problem fixed 
In the vice versa scene reverse in Anticlockwise.
The above solution takes o(N) space for matching the traversed node addresses.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should just get rid of it?
Really, it isn't possible in general case, when we can't just interpolate any element of list by others.

Comment: May be this was better as a comment :)